# How to make a text subscript or superscript in Text widget of python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, subscript, superscript

I want to convert the selected text of python `Text()` widget into **subscript** or **superscript**
I had tried this :

```
def sbscrpt():
        slctdtxt=contbox.selection_get()
        sbtxt=slctdtxt.replace(slctdtxt,'x\u00b2')
        contbox.delete(SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
        contbox.insert(INSERT,sbtxt)

contbox=Text()
```

But this not the solution as `x\u00b2` this only subscript the integers. And I want to convert a string into subscript.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind text offset to a tag in a text widget:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

t = Text(root, width=20, height=2, bd=1, padx=5, pady=5)
t.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

t.insert(END, 'H2O')
t.tag_add('sub', '1.1', '1.2')
t.tag_config('sub', offset=-4)  # Offset in pixels

root.mainloop()
```